# How to better code, when looking for substrings?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to extract the currency (along with the $ sign) from a list, and create two different currency lists which I have done. But is there a better way to code this?

The list is as below:

```
['\n\n\t\t\t\t\t$59.90\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$68.00\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\n',
 '\n\n\t\t\t\t\t$55.00\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$68.00\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\n',
 '\n\n\t\t\t\t\t$38.50\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$49.90\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\n',
 '\n\n\t\t\t\t\t$49.00\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$62.00\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\n',
 '\n\n\t\t\t\t\t$68.80\n\t\t\t\t\n\n',
 '\n\n\t\t\t\t\t$49.80\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$60.50\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\n']
```

Python code:

```py
pp_list = []
up_list = []

for u in usual_price_list:
    rep = u.replace("\n","")
    rep = rep.replace("\t","")
    s = rep.rsplit("$",1)
    pp_list.append(s[0])
    up_list.append("$"+s[1])
```

Comment: .strip will remove leading and trailing whitespace, but are you trying to get *all* of the numbers? Currently you only get the last one in each string.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: the current code does create 2 diff lists.

Comment: @Gokva I updated the code to fill you two lists

Answer (score 4):

For this kind of problem, I tend to use a lot the `re` module, as it is more readable, more maintainble and does not depend on which character surround what you are looking for :

```
import re

pp_list = []
up_list = []


for u in usual_price_list:
    prices = re.findall(r"\$\d{2}\.\d{2}", u)
    length_prices = len(prices)
    if length_prices > 0:
        pp_list.append(prices[0])
    if length_prices > 1:
        up_list.append(prices[1])
```

#### Regular Expresion Breakdown

- `$` is the end of string character, so we need to escape it
- `\d` matches any digit, so `\d{2}` matches exactly 2 digits
- `.` matches any character, so we need to escape it

If you want it you can modify the number of digits for the cents with `\d{1,2}` for matches one or two digits, or `\d*` to match 0 digit or more

Comment: I think it’s fair to assume cents have two digits ... but why enforce this constraint on the dollar portion? (Also using a `r"..."` removes the need for ugly double backslashes)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I modified the answer

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed for doing that task `re` module is useful - I would use `re.split` following way:

```
import re
data = ['\n\n\t\t\t\t\t$59.90\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$68.00\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\n',
 '\n\n\t\t\t\t\t$55.00\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$68.00\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\n',
 '\n\n\t\t\t\t\t$38.50\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$49.90\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\n',
 '\n\n\t\t\t\t\t$49.00\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$62.00\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\n',
 '\n\n\t\t\t\t\t$68.80\n\t\t\t\t\n\n',
 '\n\n\t\t\t\t\t$49.80\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$60.50\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\n']
prices = [re.split(r'[\n\t]+',i) for i in data]
prices0 = [i[1] for i in prices]
prices1 = [i[2] for i in prices]
print(prices0)
print(prices1)
```

Output:

```
['$59.90', '$55.00', '$38.50', '$49.00', '$68.80', '$49.80']
['$68.00', '$68.00', '$49.90', '$62.00', '', '$60.50']
```

Note that this will work assuming that there are solely `\n` and `\t` excluding prices and there is at least one `\n` or `\t` before first price and at least one `\n` or `\t` between prices.

`[\n\t]+` denotes any string made from `\n` or `\t` with length 1 or greater, that is `\n`, `\t`, `\n\n`, `\t\t`, `\n\t`, `\t\n` and so on

Comment: @Gokva: can you provide input data which caused error?